# Why doesn't my prime factorizer terminate?

Tags: python, prime-factoring

Using python. The 'print' step in my prime factorizer works, but it never returns 1, and the list isn't generated either. Where is my program getting stuck?

```
from math import ceil, floor, sqrt
primeList = []
primeFactorList = []

def primeList(x):
    primeList = [2]
    for n in range(2,x):
        for p in primeList:
            if n%p == 0:
                break
            elif p == primeList[-1]:
                primeList.append(n)

    return(primeList)
# Generates list of prime numbers less than x

def primeFactorizer(x):
    primeFactorList = []
    while x != 1:
        for p in primeList(x):
            if x%p == 0:
                primeFactorList.append(p)
                x = x/p
                print(x)
                break

    return(primeFactorList)
# Generates list of (possibly duplicate) prime factors of x

print(primeFactorizer(36))
```

Comment: So, you are saying that the value of `x` in `print(x)` is what you want returned from the function? Then, replace `print(x)` with `return x`.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?  They differ in the return type of `x/p`, which could be leading to floating-point rounding errors.

Comment: You are stopping early in your `primeList`,should be: `for n in range(2, int(x)+1):`

Comment: at some point you have to loop only to sqrt(x) else it takes forever.

Comment: You don't consider prime factors with powers higher than 1.

Comment: @zvone no, the print(x) is just for me to keep track of progress. i want the list of prime factors returned

Comment: @jwodder ah that might be it, but surely I won't get floating point errors when x is always an integer?

Comment: @Daniel read the loop again. that's accounted for

Comment: @StephenRauch I wouldn't want to include x in a list of prime numbers less than x...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre good point; doesn't fix my issue

Comment: @StephenRauch I see what you mean. Thanks, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`primeList`returns primes up to but less than `x`.
If `x` in `primeFactorizer` is a prime number, `x%p` is never true inside the for-loop, therefore `x` never changes.

Forget about the primes and test every number for factorization:

```
def factorize(number):
    factors = []
    for factor in range(2, number + 1):
        while number % factor == 0:
            factors.append(factor)
            number //= factor
            print(number)
        if number == 1:
            break
    return factors

print(factorize(36))
```

Comment: Ah yes that's it. Thanks

Comment: although this isn't really what I'm trying to do lol. a list of factors isn't quite what's needed for totient function business...